# Create subscription that never ends

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to communicate from children to the parent as described in the [Angular cookbook](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service). A service creates Subject through which to communicate:

`progressSubject = new Subject<ProgressMessage>`

The parent subscribes to the Subject and reacts on messages:

`this.service.progressSubject.subscribe(msg => showProgress(msg))`

Clients can use `progressSubject.next()` to send messages, which works fine.
However, if I want to subscribe the `progressSubject` to another Observable, all subscriptions terminate if the source observable completes. The parent will not react to input anymore.

```
let first = new Subject();
first.subscribe(this.service.progressSubject);
first.next(3); // value is processed by subscribers to progressSubject
first.complete();

let second= new Subject();
second.subscribe(this.service.progressSubject);
second.next(3); // original subcription to progressSubject is ended, 
                // value is not processed anymore.
```

How can I ignore the "complete" event on a Subject, so that multiple sources can connect to that Subject?

Comment: Why are you doing the complete in the first place?

Comment: Because the source could be an observable, e.g. from AJAX calls that already does the complete. I'd like to transform that source and then subscribe my Subject to the source, but filter out the complete events from the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I**

```
const first = new Subject();
const progressSubject = new Subject();
first.subscribe(progressSubject);

// is equal to

first.subscribe({
  next: val => progressSubject.next(val),
  error: err => progressSubject.error(err),
  complete: () => progressSubject.complete,
});

// if you don't need `complete` - just don't pass it )

first.subscribe({
  next: val => progressSubject.next(val),
  error: err => progressSubject.error(err),
});
```

Also we can create helper for that:

```
function skipComplete(subject){
  return {
    next: val => subject.next(val),
    error: err => subject.error(err),
  }
}

first.subscribe(skipComplete(progressSubject))
```

**II**

As @IngoBürk mentioned we can use `concat(NEVER)`:

```
first
  .pipe(concat(NEVER))
  .subscribe(progressSubject);
```

Comment: This is basically what I now use, but it feels clumsy. I was looking for something to put in a pipe...

Comment: `function skipCompleteFactory(subject){
  return {
    next: val => subject.next(val),
    error: err => subject.error(err),
  }
}

first.subscribe(skipCompleteFactory(progressSubject))`

Comment: You can pipe `concat(NEVER)` to the subject to which you subscribe. That essentially disables the complete notification as well.

Comment: @IngoBürk smart solution but it prevent stream from completion (we need to disposes the resource held by the subscription )

Comment: The question is how to prevent an observable from completing. That's what it does. So I don't get your point?

Comment: @IngoBürk The real question is `How can I ignore the "complete" event on a Subject?`

Comment: The subscription to the actual resource won't be held in my solution either. Only the subscription to the NEVER observable. There isn't really any overhead in that.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thanks, you are right! Will add your solution to the answer

Comment: You added the solution wrong. The pipe has to go to the inner subject.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, could you give an example?